# NodeJS Error when sending POST request using http.request or Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, localhost, http-post

I'm trying to send some data in NodeJS from one localhost server to another, but I'm getting a nasty error. On the server that receives the request it appears the request goes through because I'm getting an object logged to the terminal there, except its properties are null (they're supposed to be set to the properties in the req body, or null).

I get the error even if I try with Axios, which tells me that it’s not an issue with http.request or Axios. If anyone could help me understand what's going on I'd appreciate it.

Error:

```
    events.js:377
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
    
    Error: write EPROTO 8669511168:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
    
        at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:16)
    Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance 
    {
      errno: -100,
      code: 'EPROTO',
      syscall: 'write'
    }
```

The project sending the request looks like this:

Resources file

```
    const http = require('http');
    const options = {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3000,
        path: '/create',
        method: 'POST',
        header: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }
    }

    const body = {
        inquiryTotal: ‘20.00’
    }
    const stringifiedBody = JSON.stringify(body)
    
    module.exports.Inquiries = {
        create: () => {
            req = http.request(options, (res) => {
                console.log(res);
            });
            req.write(stringifiedBody); // this is an object that's already stringified to JSON
            req.end();

            /*axios.post('localhost:3000/v1/orders/create', {
            orderTotal: '21.00'
        }).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })*/
        }
    }
```

Server sending request:

```
    const resource = require('./lib/resource');
    // create server code
    resource.Inquiries.create;
```

Comment: Can you provide the axios part?

Comment: Do you mean the error? If so it’s the same as the one when I use http.request.

Comment: Not the error, but the code which you implement it using axios

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, but it's been updated. Like I said, same error.

Comment: You specify your header as `'application/json'` but you send the body as a string (`stringifiedBody `)?

Comment: try to not use `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: It still fails with the same error. This would be much easier if there was a somewhat descriptive error message being thrown lol.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are correctly setup your API endpoint, you can try this (added some comments inside the code):

```js
const axios = require("axios").default;

const body = {
  inquiryTotal: "20.00" // Use single-qupte ('') or double-quote ("") here and don't use back-quote (``)
};

module.exports.Inquiries = {
  create: () => {
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:3000/v1/orders/create", body) // Add http:// in the beginning of your url
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
};
```